# Is there a way to speed up this dupe detection query?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

This query is taking many minutes on < 10k records which is a little surprising to me. Is there a more efficient way to run a query that counts column based dupes?

```
UPDATE exportable_businesses e1 SET phone_dupe = 
 (CASE WHEN
   (SELECT COUNT(sidewalk_business_id) FROM exportable_businesses e2 WHERE query_id = #{id} AND e1.phone_number=e2.phone_number) > 1 
       THEN 'x' ELSE NULL END)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first counting the phone numbers, e.g.:

```
create temporary table phone_cnt as 
   select phone_number, count(*) as c from exportable_businesses 
   where query_id = #{id} 
   group by phone_number
```

then use the precomputed values to set the `phone_dupe` variable. Postgres should be capable of doing an update with a join, e.g.:

```
update exportable_businesses e1 
   set phone_dupe = (case when pc.c ...)
   from phone_cnt pc 
   where pc.phone_number = e1.phone_number
```

If this is still slow, you will need to create an explicit index on `phone_cnt (phone_number)` before doing the update query. This way the whole computation will take linear time, rather than quadratic, as is the case in your example with counting subqueries.

You can drop the temporary `phone_cnt` table after the query.

Comment: That's orders of magnitudes faster.  Didn't consider the temp table approach. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can use materialized view, instead of temporary table.